# Unable to boot to Live USB linux

Tags: 12.10, live-usb, usb-drive

I am trying to test different distros from a specific usb thumb drive that I have. I am installing them using UNetBootIn. The installation goes fine. I am doing this process from Xubuntu 12.10 live usb (and sometimes Linux mint 13 Mate).

However when I try to boot from it, I get to the UNetBootIn bootloader and after I choose an option, most of them seem to just hang there. Farthest I got was with Mageia which Kernel paniced about 2 seconds into the boot sequence.

The Distros I used were

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Mageia Dual Arch cd, latest release
- Linux Mint 14 Mate
- Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon
- Linux Mint LMDE Mate + Cinnamon

Is this because of a **flash drive hardware issue**? Is there something I can do to **test**? All I have tried is `fsck` and "File System check" from `Disk Utility` both of which return "clean"? Or Is it possible that all ISOs got **corrupted** upon download?

Edit: Looks to be a flash drive issue, looks like a section of my flash drive is fubar.. I got the below wierd benchmark from "Disk Utility", repeated thrice...

[image]

Comment: Please try to limit your question to Ubuntu and its official derivatives: 
According to the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), Ask Ubuntu provides support for [recognized Ubuntu flavors](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives). Your question may be welcome at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @vasa1 I understand your concern. However Both my host OS and one of the tested live versions is Ubuntu or flavour thereof, and the other distros I believe can be ignored by answerers, since I am more concerned if this is due to a issue with usb key/corrupted ISO and how to test for this, particularly the former

Comment: My point was that including other distros in the question doesn't really help. That answerers can ignore it is true. It would be better, IMO, to just have the real issue presented. Anyway, no biggie and it's your decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first test your USB and use format FAT32, e.g. in GParted, to make a fresh start.

I recommend [**MultiSystem**](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install) (http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install) as probably the best solution for what you want to achieve - a **Multi-OS live USB**.

(I use a USB HDD with a number of live Linux distributions, including Parted Magic, Redo, Recatux, etc. for backup and recovery purposes, created and updated regularly by **MultiSystem**.)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it again after reformatting as you suggest. Multisystem is definitely interesting, but what I was trying to do was try out each OS but merely one at a time, not necessarily on the USB at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I can boot ubuntu 12.10 on my old dell inspiron mini 10, following this document:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

I put the whole system in a usb disc. Have fun!